# How to force ie9 browser to read xml from server and not from cache

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-9

For anyone who is struggling with how to get ie9 to read an xml file from the server, and not from cache, here's a simple solution.  If you are able to modify the html page which is loading the xml using javascript and XmlHttpRequest, you can use a hidden iframe to force the xml to load when the page is refreshed.  For example, somewhere in the html page, add the following:

```
    <iframe src="myfile.xml" width="0" height="0" style="display:none"></iframe> <!--resolves xml caching issues-->
```

Hope this helps.  It may not be the best solution since it causes another get from the server, but I searched and searched and tried various header setting combinations such as xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache") and nothing worked in ie9!  ie8 would read the xml from the server if you closed the browser and reopened it.  But ie9 simply will not (at least not from my godaddy server).  So with this method, you can simply refresh the page, and the xml will be read from the server every time.  ie9 seems to have really applied caching to the extreme to where it's making it difficult to get fresh data.  I use godaddy hosting, I'm not sure if that adds further issues - maybe due to proxy servers.

Hope this helps.
Mark

Comment: I think caching can be solved by adding random number to the source: `myfile.xml?r=0.54891`

Answer (score 6):

Tack on a random number to the file name:

```
myfile.xml?rand=12345
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize you could do that trick in the xmlhttp.open() also.  I've seen that mentioned in other uses, but not for the xml open.  Yes, it works!  I changed my js to the following.  Thanks again, cwolves! xmlhttp.open("GET", "mydata.xml?rand=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*1001), false); xmlhttp.send();

Answer (score 3):

Karolis and cwolves solutions are much better... If I had the "reputation" points, I'd up them.

In fact it's used quite consistently, even by MS in their AJAX/WebResource implementations, except they usually append t=YearMonthDayHour24MinutesSeconds to their requests.